# why applications running in mesos is not being registered in consul?

Tags: mesos, consul, marathon, mesosphere

I an using mesos-consul and deployed it via marathon. the json config for the job is

```
{
  "id": "/mesos-consul",
  "cmd": null,
  "cpus": 0.1,
  "mem": 256,
  "disk": 0,
  "instances": 1,
  "constraints": [
    [
      "hostname",
      "LIKE",
      "fwvm.*"
    ]
  ],
  "acceptedResourceRoles": [],
  "container": {
    "type": "DOCKER",
    "volumes": [],
    "docker": {
      "image": "ciscocloud/mesos-consul",
      "network": "BRIDGE",
      "portMappings": [],
      "privileged": false,
      "parameters": [],
      "forcePullImage": false
    }
  },
  "portDefinitions": [
    {
      "port": 10000,
      "protocol": "tcp",
      "name": "default",
      "labels": {}
    }
  ],
  "args": [
    "--zk=zk://zookeeper.service.consul:2181/mesos",
    "--log-level=debug",
    "--consul",
    "--refresh=5s"
  ]
}
```

I am running consul with one server and one client.

```
consul members info
Node  Address            Status  Type    Build  Protocol  DC
vm1   10.21.10.22:8301  alive   server  0.7.5  2         devops
vm2   10.21.10.25:8301  alive   client  0.7.5  2         devops
```

mesos and marathon also looks good. still its not working

mesos-consul logs showing

```
I0410 14:45:17.917712 18194 exec.cpp:162] Version: 1.2.0
I0410 14:45:17.929821 18200 exec.cpp:237] Executor registered on agent 92704ba7-7324-4e74-a7fd-7b7c642766b2-S0
I0410 14:45:17.932121 18197 docker.cpp:850] Running docker -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock run --cpu-shares 102 --memory 268435456 --env-file /tmp/yDR5nL -v /var/lib/mesos/slaves/92704ba7-7324-4e74-a7fd-7b7c642766b2-S0/frameworks/2679cb7f-1fc2-4e8b-be3c-44f0fb54f618-0000/executors/mesos-consul.36b6d6d3-1dce-11e7-a717-0242b31c8310/runs/6a22da5d-4a33-4d1d-ada7-cd688474e4fc:/mnt/mesos/sandbox --net bridge --label=MESOS_TASK_ID=mesos-consul.36b6d6d3-1dce-11e7-a717-0242b31c8310 --name mesos-92704ba7-7324-4e74-a7fd-7b7c642766b2-S0.6a22da5d-4a33-4d1d-ada7-cd688474e4fc ciscocloud/mesos-consul --zk=zk://http://10.202.11.22:2181/mesos --log-level=debug --consul --refresh=5s
time="2017-04-10T09:15:22Z" level=info msg="Using zookeeper: zk://http://10.202.11.22:2181/mesos" 
time="2017-04-10T09:15:22Z" level=debug msg="Zookeeper address" zk="zk://http://10.202.11.22:2181/mesos"
```

Comment: Can you post the logs?

Comment: just added the logs from mesos for mesos-consui

Comment: Attached log is from Mesos not mesos-consul

Comment: exactly, this log is from mesos for mesos-consul task triggered by marathon.

Comment: docker log for mesos-consul is
 time="2017-04-11T07:53:37Z" level=info msg="Using zookeeper: zk://http://10.202.11.22:2181/mesos"
time="2017-04-11T07:53:37Z" level=debug msg="Zookeeper address" zk="zk://http://10.202.11.22:2181/mesos"
time="2017-04-11T07:55:42Z" level=fatal msg="Timed out waiting for initial ZK detection."

Answer (score 0):

got this issue fixed now. it was a network related issue. alpine linux was trying to query with

nameserver 127.0.0.1

replaced it with our dns server.